# Convergence and sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

> Determine for each of these series the real numbers $x$ for which it is convergent, and compute the sum for those $x$.
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1+x^2)^{-k}\tag a$$
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{kx}\tag b$$

I compared both of the series with the famous geometric series $$\sum_{n=0}^k a^n = 1+a+a^2+.....+a^k $$
which converges if $|a| < 1 $. So I rewrote (a) to $$ (1/(1+x^2))^k $$ 
I came to the conclusion that if (a) converges then $$ |a|=\left|1\over1+x^2\right|^k < 1  $$ 
Am I thinking right? And how do I compute the sum for these $x$?

Comment: To compute the sum, observe that when it converges (that is, when $|a| < 1$), the geometric series satisfies the formula $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^k = \frac{1}{1 - a}$.

Comment: Okay. But is there a proof of this formula?
I think I saw another formula that was $$ (1-a^{n+1})/(1-a)$$.
Whats the difference between these two?

And if i use the formula you wrote down I get the answer $$ (x^2 + 1)/x^2 $$. Is this the sum that the series converge to?

Comment: @Dr.MV's answer below gives the proof of the formula.  The difference is whether you are considering a partial sum (this gives you an expression depending on $n$, the number of terms summed), or the infinite series (for which there is no such $n$).  The Wikipedia article on the geometric series also has these formulas and some worked examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Note that the series for $f(x)$ as given by

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1+x^2)^{-k}\\\\
&=\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}
\end{align}$$

converges if $\frac{1}{1+x^2}<1$.  The $k$ is only a summation "dummy" index and does not appear after carrying out the sum.

Finally, since $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is always less than $1$ for $x\ne 0$, the series converges for all $x\ne 0$.

---

**NOTE:**

To arrive at the closed-form solution for a geometric series, note that if $S_K(x)=\sum_{k=0}^K x^k$, then $xS_K(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{K+1} x^k$.

Subtracting these expressions, we find $(1-x)S_K(x)=1-x^{K+1}$ whence dividing by $1-x$ (assuming that $x\ne 1$, yields

$$S_K(x)=\frac{1-x^{K+1}}{1-x} \tag 1$$

As $K\to \infty$, the right-hand side of $(1)$ converges if and only if $|x|<1$.  Therefore, if $|x|<1$, then

$$\lim_{K\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^K x^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: Yeah I realized that the k shouldnt be included there.
Okay so for all x except 0. But how do I compute the sum for these x? I'v got no clue in this part.

Comment: @fejz1234 I've edited to add a note that develops the closed-form for a geometric series.

Comment: I dont think there is something left for you to improve, the answer was really good ;) Thanks.